# Testing random Dynamic conditions with RSpec

Tags: ruby, dynamic, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, rspec

Ok, first ever question so apologies in advance for any obvious errors, omissions, etc.

What I'm looking to test using RSpec is the following scenario;

1) randomly select a **make** of car from a drop down menu (**element ID = carMake**)
(for example, VW, Ford, Vauxhall, BMW)

2) from this selected **make**, then randomly select a corresponding **model** of car from a drop down menu (**element ID = carModel**)

I know how to select a random value from a list,

```
makes = ["VW", "Ford", "Vauxhall", "BMW"]
random_makes = makes.sample
```

but I would like (if possible!) to randomly select from this drop-down element (as there are way too many car makes to list them all as per above).

My subsequent problem is that the **model** list is obviously dependent on the (randomly selected) car **make**.

i.e. if **Ford** is randomly selected from the **make** element, only **Ford** **models** will be presented in the **model** element, and thus only these models will then be randomly selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the randomness part of the spec (i.e. for some reason you wish to test a different choice each time)? In which case, could you explain your reasoning, because there are some problems with this approach, and a good answer may tell you how to achieve what you want without a random selection in the test. Or do you want to test some code that needs to make a random selection?

Comment: Sorry for not being more concise. I have a drop down menu on our motoring website that I want to select a single random item from (i.e. Ford). When this drop-down is populated (in this case with the selection Ford), a further drop-down menu is displayed, this time with a selection of Ford (only) models. I then want to select another single random item from this list.

Comment: OK, that is answerable (but I don't know enough Capybara/webdriver syntax to provide that for you easily). I do still think you should add *why* you want to do this, because random decisions in test scripts are usually a bad idea. Someone may be able to help you do what you want *without* making a random selection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason I want this to be random is so I'm not hitting the same (resulting) make and model page each time I run this test. By making them random each time I run the test I'm at least testing a different resulting page.

Comment: OK. It's not part of your question, so I'll leave that. But, separate to your question, have a think about what that means for test repeatability, and how you expect to respond to a reported test failure. Also, how you will use your test to prove that a failure is fixed.